# Generate previous work day

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, saql

I want to display sales from yesterday but the company is close Saturday and Sunday. So when the day is Monday I need to return Friday sales. But if the day is Tuesday I can return Monday sales.

Is there a way to do a conditional filter in Analytics ?

For example :

```
if today() == 'Monday' then filter q by 'Date' in ["3 day ago" .. "3 day ago"]
else filter q by 'Date' in ["1 day ago" .. "1 day ago"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a thing such as conditional filtering.

But you can create a query with "case when" and generate the value "3 days ago" or "1 days ago". Then insert that value in your main query with a cell binding.